# Automate looking for calls to an offset of a structure

Tags: ghidra

I want to automate the search for function calls to a function that does not live in the binary and where the function address is passed, via a pointer to a struct, at runtime through a function parameter.

As an example, the first parameter of a JNI class is `JNIEnv*` which is a struct that contains, among other things, pointers to JNI functions. If you decompile a JNI function, you might see something like this:

```
Java_com_example_ExampleClass_exampleMethod(JNIEnv*, ...) {
   ...
   clazz = (*(*env)->FindClass)(env,jniClass);
   ...
}
```

Using Ghidra's pcode API, is it possible to automate locating all references to the `FindClass` function? For reference, the call to `FindClass` will look something like the following in x86 assembly and pcode.

```
  000fd2be 8b 0f           MOV        ECX,dword ptr [EDI]
                                              $U16f0:4 = LOAD ram(EDI)
                                              ECX = COPY $U16f0


  000fd2c7 ff 51 18        CALL       dword ptr [ECX + 0x18]
                                              $U3a0:4 = INT_ADD ECX, 24:4
                                              ESP = INT_SUB ESP, 4:4
                                              STORE ram(ESP), 0xfd2ca:4
                                              $U16f0:4 = LOAD ram($U3a0)
                                              CALLIND $U16f0
```

Comment: i was going to suggest did you try  [JniAnalyzer mentioned in this query](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25760/getting-the-algorithm-used-inside-this-so-file/25795#25795)  but the nick looks like it is related

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this using the pcode API, you will have to examine the arguments to the [PTRSUB](https://ghidra.re/courses/languages/html/additionalpcode.html#cpui_ptrsub) operation, which is the equivalent of `->` on the C level.

> A PTRSUB performs the simple pointer calculation, input0 + input1, but also indicates explicitly that input0 is a reference to a structured data-type and one of its subcomponents is being accessed. Input0 is a pointer to the beginning of the structure, and input1 is a byte offset to the subcomponent. As an operation, PTRSUB produces a pointer to the subcomponent and stores it in output.

Note that the `PTRSUB` operation is not a part of the raw pcode posted in the question, but it is inserted by the decompiler during the analysis process. Quoting the documentation again:

> The following opcodes are not generated as part of the raw translation of a machine instruction into p-code operations, so none of them can be used in a processor specification. But, they may be introduced at a later stage by various analysis algorithms.

The following code will find all calls to a structure offset in a given function:

```
DecompileResults results = decompiler.decompileFunction(function,
    decompiler.getOptions().getDefaultTimeout(), monitor);
HighFunction hfunc = results.getHighFunction();

for(PCodeOpAST op : hfunc.getPcodeOps()) {
    if (op.getOpcode() == PcodeOp.CALLIND) {
        Varnode funcAddress = op.getInput(0);

        while (funcAddress.getDef().getOpcode() == PcodeOp.LOAD)
            funcAddress = funcAddress.getDef().getInput(1);

        if (funcAddress.getDef().getOpcode() == PcodeOp.PTRSUB) {
            Varnode struct = funcAddress.getDef().getInput(0);
            Varnode field = funcAddress.getDef().getInput(1);

            DataType structDataType = struct.getHigh().getDataType();
            while(structDataType instanceof Pointer || structDataType instanceof TypeDef) {
                if (structDataType instanceof Pointer)
                    structDataType = ((Pointer)structDataType).getDataType();
                else if (structDataType instanceof TypeDef)
                    structDataType = ((TypeDef)structDataType).getDataType();
            }

            if (structDataType instanceof Structure && field.isConstant()) {
                Structure structure = (Structure) structDataType;
                int offset = (int)field.getOffset();

                DataTypeComponent component = structure.getComponentAt(offset);
                System.out.println("Call to " + component.getFieldName() +
                    " in " + structure.getName());
                for (int i = 1; i < op.getNumInputs(); ++i) {  // 0 is the function address, 1+ are arguments
                    System.out.println(" with argument " + i + " = " + op.getInput(i).getAddress());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can search for all references to the FindClass field in the program instead, but note that this will list all types of references, not just calls:

```
DataType jniEnvDataType = program.getDataTypeManager().getDataType("/jni_all.h/JNIEnv");
Accumulator<LocationReference> accumulator = new ListAccumulator<>();
ReferenceUtils.findDataTypeReferences(accumulator, jniEnvDataType, "FindClass",
    program, TaskMonitor.DUMMY);
for(LocationReference location : accumulator) {
    System.out.println(location.getLocationOfUse());
}
```

(this is basically the equivalent of "Find Uses of JNIEnv.FindClass ..." in the UI)

Comment: nice solution for the problem!